# Additional onchange event for FileUpload with validators

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**Edit** 2013-11-07: I see a lot of views on this question.  If this question and answer do not help you, please let me know in some way so I can fix it.

---

I have a `FileUpload` control in my .aspx file.  I have a couple validators tied to it (a `CustomValidator` for file size and a `RegularExpressionValidator` for file extension type).  I would like to add a client-side `onchange` event to my `FileUpload` to fire after the validators fire, but when I do this...

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="upl1" onchange="disableEnableUploadButton()" />
```

...the onchange handler seems to get overwritten by the validators.  The same thing happens when I add it as an attribute in the CodeBehind's `Page_Load` method.

Is there an easy way to fix this, hopefully without adding an on-client-load event to dig through the page and modify attributes of the resulting file input?

My current solution is to add another `CustomValidator` or modify the one that already exists, and put the code I want in its `ClientValidationFunction` script block.  However, this does not fire when a user cancels the file input's file dialogue box.  And it's really crude.

---

**Edit:** Here's a working (as far as I can tell) solution, trimmed a bit.  The important part for fixing the problem I had is in the final four lines.  It's not Yuriy's exact solution, but his solution lead to this. .bind() is an old jQuery function; I'd probably use a different function like .on(), but we're running an old jQuery library.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    function disableEnableUploadButton(btnID, uplID) {
        var button = document.getElementById(btnID);
        var uploader = document.getElementById(uplID);
        button.disabled = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < uploader.Validators.length; i++) {
            // Looping through each validator.
            if (uploader.Validators[i].isvalid == false) {
                // Looks like this validator isn't valid.  Better disable the upload button.
                button.disabled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function validateFileSize(source, e) {
        var maxSize = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMaxFileSize.ClientID %>').value;
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('<%=upl1.ClientID %>');
        if (!window.FileReader || !fileInput.files || !fileInput.files[0]) {
            // No files attached.  That means no files that are too large are attached.
            e.IsValid = true;
        }
        else if (fileInput.files[0].size > maxSize) {
            // Looks like someone's trying to give us a lot of bytes.  No, thank you, Mister User.
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="upl1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload file" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valExtension" ControlToValidate="upl1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Unallowed file type for upload" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valFileSize" runat="server" ControlToValidate="upl1" ClientValidationFunction="validateFileSize" ErrorMessage="File too large" OnServerValidate="valFileSize_ServerValidate" >
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMaxFileSize" runat="server" />
</asp:CustomValidator>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This is not in a function, so it fires when the markup is being processed.  That's why it appears after everything else.
    var upl = document.getElementById('<%=upl1.ClientID %>');
    $(upl).bind('change', function () { disableEnableUploadButton('<%=valExtension.ClientID %>', '<%=valFileSize.ClientID %>', '<%=btnUpload.ClientID %>'); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it on client side, not on server side. You can attach multiple event handlers to an element's event using `$addHandler` statement (You have to have ScriptManager added to your ASPX page for this to work).

In your case if you do

```
$addHandler($get("upl1"), "change", disableEnableUploadButton);
```

It will chain this new handler to whatever already happen to be there. If you don't want to add this code directly to client-side code, you can generate it server-side via `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: Would `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` have to be called on postBacks, too, or would the first load be enough?

Comment: If possible, I still suggest adding this to client-side (ASPX/JS). Otherwise yes, it will have to be called every time page loads - both initial and postback.